# Find unique IDs based on matching dates, data.table r

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data, like so

```
library(data.table)

data1 <- data.table(
  id = c(seq(1:5)),
  date = c(as.Date("2021-05-05"),as.Date("2021-05-04"),as.Date("2021-05-03"),as.Date("2021-05-02"),as.Date("2021-05-01")),
  var = c(rep("var1",5))
)

data2 <- data.table(
  id = c(seq(1:5)),
  date = c(as.Date("2021-05-05"),as.Date("2020-05-04"),as.Date("2020-05-03"),as.Date("2020-05-02"),as.Date("2020-05-01")),
  var = c(rep("var2",5))
)

data3 <- data.table(
  id = c(seq(1:5)),
  date = c(as.Date("2021-05-05"),as.Date("2020-07-04"),as.Date("2020-07-03"),as.Date("2020-07-02"),as.Date("2020-07-01")),
  var = c(rep("var3",5))
)

data4 <- data.table(
  id = c(seq(1:5)),
  date = c(as.Date("2021-05-05"),as.Date("2020-07-04"),as.Date("2020-07-03"),as.Date("2020-07-02"),as.Date("2020-07-01")),
  var = c(rep("var4",5))
)

data <- rbind(data1,data2,data3,data4)
data <- data[order(id)]
```

I would like to find and keep those unique IDs (including keeping the dates), where date for var1, var2, and var3 is equal to one another. I dont care about var4. In the above data, only id 1 would match these criteria, so I want to end up with something like this:

```
data_final <- data.table(
  id = 1,
  date_var1 = as.Date("2021-05-05"),
  date_var2 = as.Date("2021-05-05"),
  date_var3 = as.Date("2021-05-05")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dcast` to reshape to wide format after filtering - grouped by 'id', filter the 'id's having all values in 'date' are same.  Then do the `dcast` on the filtered data to reshape back to wide format

```
data1 <- data[data[, .I[uniqueN(date[var %in% paste0("var", 1:3)]) == 1],id]$V1
         ][var != 'var4']
out1 <- dcast(data1, id ~ paste0('date_', var), value.var = 'date')
```

-output

```
> out1
   id  date_var1  date_var2  date_var3
1:  1 2021-05-05 2021-05-05 2021-05-05
```

Comment: I am not sure this would work. I should have specified. The actual dataset is approx. 15 million rows, so i assume reshaping the data would not work?

Comment: This part: [var %in% paste0("var", 1:3)], I wouldnt know its the first 3 rows necessarily?

Comment: @epiNS your post says you are interested in only var1, var2, var3 i.e. `where date for var1, var2, and var3 is equal to one another. I dont care about var4.`. I could have explicitly showed `c("var1", "var2", "var3")` instead of `paste0("var", 1:3)` to create the values